# Ruby on Rails error after updating rubygems: " Failed to find gems [] >= 0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just installed Ruby on Rails, and while trying to follow [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) I kept running into a warning telling me to update rubygems and then run `gem pristine --all`. I updated using `sudo gem install rubygems-update` and tried running `gem pristine --all`, which resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems [] >= 0
```

I also tried running `bin/rails server` on a blog application and I got the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/mariana/Documents/RD-anagram/rails-test/blog/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I also cannot run `rails --version`, because I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/mariana/.gem/ruby/1.9.1:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have the bundler gem missing.

Do:-

```
gem install rails    
[sudo] gem install bundler
bundle install
gem install railties
```

If the above code doesnt work, you can do a 
`rvm implode` to reinstall rvm. Note that the command recursively delete all rvm environments.